# NPV function in r

Tags: r

I am trying to manually add the NPV formula but I am getting the error message Error: attempt to apply non-function

npv<- (2520/(1+0.10))+ (2520(1+0.10)^2)+ (2520(1+0.10)^3)

Please let me know why am I getting this error message and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably, we need the `*`

```
(2520/(1+0.10))+ (2520*(1+0.10)^2)+ (2520*(1+0.10)^3)
[1] 8694.229
```